# How to make a text box have rounded corners?

Tags: html, css

I have this wireframe http://problemio.com/problemionewest.pdf and you see on the top-right there is a text box that has rounded corners.

Is that done with css only or image and css?  I have an image that was provided to me, but would much rather just do it with css.  In any case, I don't know how to do it either way lol, so any help would be great!

The current version I have is here: http://www.problemio.com

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use CSS to do that, but it wouldn't be supported in IE8-. You can use some site like http://borderradius.com to come up with actual CSS you'd use, which would look something like this (again, depending on how many browsers you're trying to support):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

Answer (score 19):

This can be done with CSS3:

```
<input type="text" />

input
{
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UbSkn/1/

---

However, an alternative would be to put the `input` inside a `div` with a rounded background, and no border on the `input`

Comment: Are you talking CSS rounded corners? Because [it looks like that works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Bbx/), in Chrome at least.

Comment: @curt this can also be done using the reference to the class of the input field, right?

Comment: And how widely is css 3 supported by different browsers?

Comment: The focus line should be disabled.

Comment: input { outline: none; }